# Angular2 default active link on site load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using angular2 and angular2 [routerLinkActive] on each link, to set the active link. This all works fine. When the user clicks on a link, the route becomes active and the link gets the "active" class injected and I can style accordingly.

However in the route setup I set up a default route like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'gettiingstarted', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

This works in as far as the page now successfully loads the "gettingstarted" component when the user first navigates to the page, but unfortunately the router link has not had the "active" class injected at this point, so is not correctly styled. The only way to get the active class is to actually click the link.

Does anyone know how I can get [routerLinkActive] mechanism to work on page load?

**Update**
Here is the code html for the link itself:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['gettingstarted']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
```

Comment: Look at the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html), there are couple of options you can try `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}`, for example.

Comment: show how you have your `routerLinkActive` is used, and the `route` you're navigating to

Comment: why are you using `=['gettingstarted']` instead of `="gettingstarted"`?

Comment: and `[routerLinkActive]=` instead of `routerLinkActive=`?

Comment: My understanding is that angular2 supports both of these syntaxes, certainly this syntax has not been an issue anywhere else. I have tried the "{exact: true}" and this had no effect.

Comment: try `redirectTo: '/gettiingstarted'`, add a slash before `gettiingstarted`

Comment: Changing the syntax as suggested also made no difference. To re-iterate though, the links generally work, there is just an issue where the default link does not have the 'active' class when the page first loads.

Comment: @Slicc, what about adding slash?

Comment: @Maximus, just tried that as well, no luck I'm afraid. The strange this is the gettingstarted component is the first page the user sees when the app is first loaded, it is just the link that does not have the 'active' class unless it is clicked.

Comment: I've also tried updating the latest angular2 version (4.0.3)

Comment: what is the url in a browser before and after the redirect?

Comment: "http://localhost/" before, then "http://localhost/gettingstarted" afterwards

Comment: don't know then, everything seems legit. maybe create a plunker?

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the following in the constructor of the app.component.ts file fixed it:

```
        this.router.navigate(['/gettingstarted']);
```

Not sure it is the recommended solution, but fixes it for my case.

Comment: definitely not a recommended approach, will post an answer if i found any other

Answer (score 1):

Use `isActive: true` in routerLinkActiveOptions like this

`<a routerLinkActive="active-link" 
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true, isActive: true }">Home</a>`